# Show that in ℝ[x], no polynomial of odd degree > 1 is irreducible.

Tags: calculus

I think that logically, I understand the concept because no matter what polynomial you have you can always factor it into something with a x to a power plus or minus some real number, and that real number can be a fraction, or an irrational number, or a whole number. However, I am not sure how to write this in a reasonable mathematical way.

Comment: How can you «factor into something with a x to a power plus or minus some real number» the polynomial $x^2+x+1$?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez odd degree.

Comment: This is usually proved using the intermediate value theorem. Do you have access to this theorem?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/689575/proof-that-every-polynomial-of-odd-degree-has-one-real-root

Comment: $x^3+x^2+x+1$, then!

Comment: Right. This question just screams "I'm a duplicate".

Comment: @user2345215 I found a bunch of questions about whether an odd-degree polynomial has a root, but nothing else about whether one is irreducible.

Comment: @MJD Well it's about not being irreducible, so how is being reducible not an obvious special case of having a root?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** You only need $\deg p\ge1$ odd. Can you compute $\lim\limits_{x\to-\infty}p(x)$ and $\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty}p(x)?$ What does this tell you?

Comment: limx→−∞ for a polynomial of odd degree would be -∞ and limx→+∞ would be ∞.

Comment: @Megan: Yes. And polynomials are continuous. So the graph must cross the $y=0$ line and has a root.

Comment: Ah yes I do see how the intermediate value theorem works here now. Thank you for the assistance

Answer (score 5):

A polynomial of odd degree always has a root. Indeed by looking at the highest degree term, $\lim_{x \to \infty} p(x) = \infty$ and $\lim_{x \to -\infty} p(x) = -\infty$ (or the reverse if the leading coefficient is negative), so you can apply the intermediate value theorem. And of course, if a polynomial has a root it's reducible.

Comment: Is this because, for example if you have a factor of x^5+1 then x=-1 is a root, but for a polynomial of even degree, say x^4+1 does not have a root because there is no number x such that x^4=-1 in the real numbers?

Comment: I think you're a bit confused. A polynomial of even degree can of course has a root, for example $x^4-1$ has roots $1, -1$. But some don't. However, a polynomial of odd degree always has a root because of the intermediate value theorem.

Comment: Oh yes, sorry I should have been clearer. I do understand how polynomials of even degrees work. Can you explain how the IVT is applied here though, I don't quite understand how that works with this.

Comment: $x^4+1$ does not have a real root, but is still reducible over $\mathbb{R}$, as it factors as $$x^4+1 = (x^2-\sqrt{2}x+1)(x^2+\sqrt{2}x+1)$$

Comment: @Megan: See my edit.

Comment: The hint is equivalent to what the OP wants to show. The OP wants to understand why a polynomial of odd degree always has a (real) root.

Comment: @NicholasStull The OP is considering polynomials with *odd* degree. Your example has even degree.

Comment: @FlybyNight: Be careful, it's not equivalent! Every real polynomial of degree $> 2$ is reducible, but it doesn't always have a root...

Comment: Subject to the hypothesis that the polynomial have an odd degree, *it is equivalent*.

Comment: @FlybyNight I know.  But I was addressing the polynomial she mentioned in her post.  (i.e., a polynomial not having a real root is not sufficient to show it is irreducible)

Comment: @FlybyNight If you want to get pedantic, two true things are always equivalent, yes. In any case what you say isn't obvious, and I believe my hint will help the OP.

Comment: Be careful, this is not pedantry. Insisting on truth is what mathematicians do. You have changed your original post considerably since my original comment. I think it is now useful.

Comment: @FlybyNight Sorry if my comment seemed irrelevant.  I was simply trying to clarify that not having a real root is not enough to conclude a polynomial is irreducible.  It is true that every odd degree polynomial must have a real root, hence cannot be irreducible, but no polynomial of degree $\geq 3$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{R}$ either, which is what I was hinting at.

Answer (score 1):

A polynomial $p(x) \in \Bbb R[x]$ with $\deg p$ odd always has a real zero $\alpha$; thus we have $p(x) = (x - \alpha)q(x)$ with $q(x) \in \Bbb R[x]$, showing that $p(x)$ is reducible in $\Bbb R[x]$.

A complete proof such $p(x)$ must have a real root may be found in my answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/742580/proof-that-every-odd-polynomial-has-a-real-root-not-a-duplicate), only a mouse click away!

Hope this helps.  Cheerio,

and of course,

***Fiat Lux!!!***

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  Complex roots of polynomials in $\mathbb{R}[x]$ **always** come in pairs.  Further, the total number of roots (counting multiplicity) is always $deg(f)$.  So what can you deduce if $deg(f)$ is odd?