# Every polynomial of odd degree $\ge 3$ over $\mathbb{R}[x]$ is reducible over $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, irreducible-polynomials

> I need to prove that every polynomial of odd degree $\ge 3$ over $\mathbb{R}[x]$ is reducible over $\mathbb{R}$.

If $p(x)$ is my polynomial, then I just have to prove that $p(x)$ has one real root, right? If I can do it, then I must only apply the division theorem and divide by $x-\alpha$ when $\alpha$ is the root. I've found some arguments like [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/689575/proof-that-every-polynomial-of-odd-degree-has-one-real-root) but they use too much analysis and I'm on a ring theory course. How can I prove this in a more abstract way?

Comment: If you can also prove this for odd degrees $<3$, then you can just say odd degree...

Comment: For what it's worth, every real polynomial whose degree is greater than $2$ is $\mathbb R$-reducible.

Comment: @Guelando There is no proof of what you want without using analysis (real or complex).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Try to prove that if $\alpha$ is a complex root of $P(x) \in \Bbb R[x]$ then also $\overline{\alpha}$ is a root of $P(x)$. Then deduce that $P(x)$ must have an even number of non real roots.

Comment: How do you know that $p(x)$ has a complex root?

Comment: Since $\Bbb C$ is the algebraic closure of $\Bbb R$, all the roots of $p(x)$ must be in $\Bbb C$.

Comment: Maybe you want to read [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_algebra#Algebraic_proofs) and [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/165996/is-there-a-purely-algebraic-proof-of-the-fundamental-theorem-of-algebra).

Comment: I assumed that we could use  FTA.

Comment: The OP said that he is not satisfied with another answer since it uses analysis (that is, IVT), and a fair answer should have pointed out that there is no escape.