# Prove that the odd polynomial equation $p(x)=0$ has at least one real solution (use intermediate value theorem)

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, complex-analysis, analysis

Let $a_0,a_1,....a_n$ be real numbers and $p(x) = a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+...a_1x+a_0$ for $x \in R$

I am trying to prove that the odd polynomial equation $p(x)=0$ has at least one real solution by using the intermediate value theorem.

Here's how I started it.

We can assume without loss of generality that $a_n=1$ and can write $p(x)= x^n(1+\frac{a_{n-1}}{x}+\frac{a_{n-2}}{x^2}+...\frac{a_0}{x_n})$

How can I show that there exists $M>0$ such that $x\leq -M$ implies $p(x) <0$
and
$M>0$ such that $x\geq M$ implies $p(x) >0$

Comment: Hint: Look at the behavior of $p(x)$ as $x\to -\infty$ and as $x\to\infty$.

Comment: When $M$ is very large, all the $\frac {a_i}{x^j}$ tend to zero, so eventually the number in the parenthesis becomes positive. Also see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/689575/proof-that-every-polynomial-of-odd-degree-has-one-real-root

Comment: I am giving this response as a comment, rather than answer for three reasons: (1) You specifically asked about the use of the IVT (2) I *suspect* without being sure, that if a polynomial is of **even** degree, then it can **not** be an odd polynomial (3) I *suspect* without being sure, that when the polynomial has all real coefficients, that the complex roots **must** come in conjugate pairs.  Assuming so, since a polynomial of odd degree must have an odd number of roots, one of these roots must be real.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: consider the limits $\lim_{x\to \infty}p(x)$ and $\lim_{x\to -\infty}p(x)$. If these are large and small enough you might be able to find such $M$’s quite easily.